# htaccess adding ending slash to some images and not others

Tags: .htaccess

New to htaccess... All files exist despite 404. There are actual 50+ images in this one folder but 3 images are getting a slash added to the end.

not working:

http://shawnrieger.dev/img/photography/small/20100402153906_s.jpg/
http://shawnrieger.dev/img/photography/small/20140404123054_s.jpg/
http://shawnrieger.dev/img/photography/small/20130330110114_s.jpg/

an example of working:

http://shawnrieger.dev/img/photography/small/20160913190428_s.jpg
http://shawnrieger.dev/img/photography/small/20120613091849_s.jpg
http://shawnrieger.dev/img/photography/small/20120713102800_s.jpg

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy/$ /parts/pages/privacy-policy.php
RewriteRule ^project/([^/]+)/$ /parts/pages/project.php?id=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$

RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
    </FilesMatch>

    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must avoid adding trailing slash for real files and also reorder your rules.

Have it like this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
    </FilesMatch>

    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^privacy-policy/$ /parts/pages/privacy-policy.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^project/([^/]+)/$ /parts/pages/project.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Make suer to clear your browser cache before you test this change.

Comment: htaccess is very confusing. thank you, this is working great. I'll try to read more on this topic.